# Front of House and Monitor Placement in Mixer

Tags: speakers, mixer, pa

You are working with a noob. I have a Yamaha Emx512c powered mixer that has two channels. I know next to nothing other than the mixer has two separate powered channels. Each channel runs 500W at 4ohms and 300 W at 8 ohms.  Hopefully the back is pictures below. Speaker wise I have:

Pair of Samson RS15 (225W at 8 ohms)

Four Bagend Ta-12c (200W at 8 ohms)

I THINK when you daisy chain speakers, that puts the speakers in parallel. Since all my speakers are the same wattage, in my case if I daisy chain 2 speakers, the impedance is now 4 ohms. As I understand it, that's the most I can chain without blowing my amp.

The mixer also has a separate output for powered monitors, but I'm ignoring that right now since I have none. Before I blow up my stuff the question is do I plug a 1/4 jack into one channel, output it at one speaker and then daisy chain to a second speaker? Or does that daisy chained speaker for back into to the pa somehow. Whatever the answer is there, I assume I repeat that in the other side?

Also is there anyway to take advantage of my other two Bagend Speakers if I am thinking right?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're correct on the connections. Daisy-chaining any two of those speakers will result in an impedance of 4 Ohms, so you could use a 15" and a 12" in parallel for each channel.

Using one of each for foldback won't be that satisfactory, though, as you'll be controlling the volume of the pair at the same time, so FOH and monitor will go up and down together, using, say, the 12" as monitors.

Your best bet would be, for now, to obtain a separate power amp of some kind to connect the monitor  line out of the Yamaha to its input, and run the remaining 2 12" as foldback - assuming that new addition has a minimum 4 Ohms capability. That would then mean controlling foldback from the Yamaha, but with only one mix to both passive 12".

Another option *maybe* is to use one channel of the Yamaha for FOH, the other for foldback, and that gives the possibility to pan between the two. But you're still only going to use 4 speakers at most. It's common that a PA amp will deal with only FOH, and have the porting for 'monitor out' - a line level output that goes to another amp and speaker/s.

Comment: Sweet thanks man! So I did misspeak, I only have a total of 2 Bagends and ultimately we want more monitors. What I am thinking is using the 2 15s in series at FOH. Then two 12s as the monitors thru a separate PA as you suggested. What I'm unsure of is I also may have access to a powered monitor and I'm not sure how I'd go about adding that. If that was the case I could have 3 monitors (2 passive thru a new PA and 1 active) but not sure if that causes damage.

Comment: I've managed without monitors for the last 20 odd yrs. Only time I needed them was playing keys 30' back behind the p.a. (for vox) with a big band in front. For smaller gigs with say 4/5 piece by careful placing of FOH speakers there really should be no need. It only adds to the sound pressure on stage, which one day you'll come to regret, believe me!

Comment: @Tim  I'm all for keeping levels moderate, and will always consider the possibility of doing without separate monitors.  But there are many setups where having a monitor CLOSE to you (therefore doesn't have to be loud) is enormously helpful.  It's very hard to play to the echo off the back wall of the hall.  And yes, IEMs are great in a well-rehearsed band with a good sound operator.  But not all gigs are like that!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is how you connect two speakers to one output. No loop-back.

I suggest you attack the two big speakers to one channel for FOH, the two smaller ones to the other for monitoring.   Then you have individual control over FOH and monitor levels.

Stereo PA is very over-rated, and can actually be counterproductive.  Few of your audience will be located so as to get the proper balance.

Comment: Please don't attack the speakers, they're not far from ohmless..!